# summing up overlapping time in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

So working on a problem here where I have to get the overlapping time sum from using timestart and timestop columns of 2 different equipments. if line1 started and stop then start and stop and start and stop and all 3 times there is an overlap, then I need to take the very first starttime and the very last stoptime and sum them up. Pictures below my illustrate the idea. Temp1 is a copy of original but without any of the extra details. I just need to do the sum according to the Line 1 or Line2.

*Ok so if we give attention to the image with the circled data above, what needs to happen is I need to take the total time from 18:10-18:47 because both 1061 and 1062 overlap each other. So I will have two more colums inner joined into the temp1 that will group the data by Hours and another column that will show the total time the Line was down for.*

this is a link to the http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e33ff/1

I have searched for a solution to this but either the solution is in Oracle or people have used sql-server 2014 to make it easier by using the analytical functions such as Lead(), but i am using server 2008

In my sql fiddle i have added a table 'results' that will give you a glimpse of what should the results look like. The entry in there corresponds to the pkid=1065 and pkid=1066. Please help out or give some hints on how to tackle it.

[image: Original Table]

[image: Sample of OVerlapping]

[image: Sample of Overlapping 2]

Comment: "then I need to take the very first starttime and the very last stoptime and sum them up" ... what do you mean by first and last?  Is this based on the ID?

Comment: How do you want to sum datetime values? Can you give expected result set?

Comment: You could have spent few minutes to write proper description with example data and expected results, now it's quite difficult to understand what you actually mean. My guess is that this is some sort of gaps and islands problem where you want to combine overlapping ranges into one, maybe per id

Comment: Ok so if we give attention to the image with the circled data above, what needs to happen is I need to take the total time from 18:10-18:47 because both 1061 and 1062 overlap each other. So I will have two more colums inner joined into the temp1 that will group the data by Hours and another column that will show the total time the Line was down for.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work to partition over the line number and select min and max times?

```
select 
    d.PkID, 
    Line,
    d.dateentry, 
    TimeStart,
    Timestop, 
    Min(TimeStart) over (partition by line) as TimeStartPartition,
    Max(Timestop) over (partition by line) as TimestopPartition,
    e.TimeL1,
    f.TimeL2
```

Comment: I'm afraid this query doesn't employ any logic to identify overlapping intervals.